# How can I secure my database credentials when using shared hosting and no access to outside the webroot?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have all of my database credentials within an include file that I wanted to place outside of my webroot file.

However, my shared hosting plan does not allow me to place files outside of the webroot.  Would I have to look at encrypting my file in some way to make sure my credentials are secure?

I had read a method to produce a kind of fake 404 page, but that doesnt sound very secure to me at all.

I've also taken the step of creating a read-only user account so that if my account is compromised then at least nothing can be overwritten or dropped, but I obviously want to be as secure as I can given the limitations.

Comment: the short answer is your not going to be able to realistically achieve your goal. If security is that important to you - get another host with better hosting options. And if someone 'gets' access to your account, then 'read only' access is not going to help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't

Best what is possible is create php file which will be interpreted by hosting service.

```
<?php

$DB_USER = 'your_user';
$DB_PASS = 'your_pass';
$DB_INSTANCe= 'your_instance';
```

When someone will access your file from web browser he won't see anything. When you need your file just include it.

You could also add some .htaccess (probably) so no one using web browser will be able to access your file.

Someone who has read access to the same physical host as you will be sadly able to access this file, and there is no way to prevent that.

Comment: Can you explain how someone could write to a database that the only credentials they have are an account that is read only?

Comment: Apart from the htaccess stuff outlined in another answer then this is what I do anyway, so thanks for the clarification

Comment: if I have an read access I could simply read the file.

Ex: Let Alice be owner. Now BagGuy has read access to her file, so he writes php file in place where he can write which simply includes yours. Now he can do whatever he like with your credentials.

Answer (score 1):

If the server is running apache and you are allowed to override the directives then this could be achieved using by creating a .htaccess file in the webroot with the following lines, be sure to replace <FILENAME> (including the <>) with the name of the file you would like to deny access to.

```
#Deny access to the .htaccess file

<Files ~ "^\.htaccess">

Order allow,deny

Deny from all

</Files>

#Deny the database file

<Files ~ "^\<FILENAME>$">

Order allow,deny

Deny from all

</Files>
```